# How to populate the form fields through routing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs,can someone please help to resolve my issue.I have an index.html page,where it has a logo and some message,along with that i have a text box where i ask employeeID as a input.On entering the employeeID i would want the page to be routed to portal.html ,where i will have to display the the employee details in a form.But the form displays blank input fields.I am using restservice which would return a JSON object as below

[
{
Emp_Id: 123,
Emp_Name: "abc",
Email: "abc@jkl.com",
Primary_Skill: "angularjs",
}
]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap 3 css -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular.js -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/basicPage.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="routeApp">

<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

portal.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Employee Details</p>
<form>
Employee Id : <input type="text" ng-model="empPortal.Emp_Id" required></br></br>
Employee Name : <input type="text" ng-model="empPortal.Emp_Name" required></br></br>
Email Id : <input type="text" ng-model="empPortal.Email" required></br></br>
Primary Skill : <input type="text" ng-model="empPortal.Primary_Skill" required></br></br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

main.html

```
<form>
 <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="ex1">Welcome to the portal!</h1>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>COMPETENCY MANAGEMENT is the system's ability to connect various competencies/skill sets.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="one">
        <h2 class ="ex2">Please enter your Employee ID</h2>
        <label>Employee ID:</label>
        <input ng-model="empID" size= "15" required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
       </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <img ng-src="{{image}}" class="img-rounded" width="380" height="220"> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>  
</form>
```

app.js

```
var routeApp = angular.module("routeApp", ["ngRoute"]);
routeApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "partials/main.html",
        controller : "empDetailsCtrl"
    })
     .when("/submit", {
        templateUrl : "partials/portal.html",
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    });
});

routeApp.controller("empDetailsCtrl",['$scope','$http','$log','$location',function ($scope,$http,$log,$location) {
    $scope.image = "http://hrm-storitve.si/uploads/files/slika_13x.jpg";
    $scope.submit = function(){
        if ($scope.empID != null){
            $http.get('http://localhost:5555/com.vog.jersey.first/rest/empService/getEmployeeDetails?employeeId='+$scope.empID')
                    .success(function(data)
                            {
                          $scope.empPortal = data;
                          $location.path('/submit');
                            })
                     .error(function(err){
                         $log.error(err);
                     })
        }
            else
                {
                $location.path('/');
                }
        };
}]);
```

Comment: take  `$rootScope.empPortal = data` and inject root scope in `empDetails` ctrl,
`routeApp.controller("empDetailsCtrl",['$scope','$http','$log','$location','$rootScope',function ($scope,$http,$log,$location,$rootScope) {`

Comment: $rootScope is bad practice, i suggest you pass the empID through the url and make the http get in the submit controller if you have one..

Comment: but he does not have a controller to portal view.

Comment: But if he wants to mess with scope inside the portal view he should have one...

Comment: @ajs, you have your code wrong, if you have taken `<div ng-view></div>` in `index.html`, there is no need of html tags again in `portal.html`. also `portal.html` should have a controller, but you didn't mention in your code.